# No compatibility tab in exe properties

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-registry

The compatibility tab is missing in some programs. For example: nslookup.exe , powershell.exe . If I make a copy of this file nearby, then there will be a compatibility tab in it. This means that these exe files can have this tab,and the prohibition for this tab is set specifically for a specific path.

Where are this paths to the programs for which this prohibition is set listed, and how to programmatically remove this prohibition for certain programs? May be I should to edit some parameter in registry?

​

> What problem are you trying to solve by enabling this?

I want to get correct data from this powershell code while screen scaling is enabled (for example 125%):

```
[Void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens.Bounds.Size
# Result: ❌2048    864 (Real resolution is 2560x1080)
```

So I need to change high DPI settings to "Application":
[image]
If I create a copy(powershell — copy.exe) near powershell.exe, I can set high DPI setting, and this code launched from powershell — copy.exe returns correct data(✔️2560   1080). This means that powershell.exe can have this tab, prohibition is not inside the exe. As I understand prohibition somewhere located, and looks something like this (just an idea):

```
Compatibility tab prohibition list:
C:\...
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
etc
```

Comment: While it is curious that the compatibility menus is disabled for some programs it is not entirely surprising for programs that came with the OS because they can be assumed to be "100% compatible".  What problem are you trying to solve by enabling this?

Comment: @Mokubai, Hello. I answered you in the question message.